# Method to measure "distance" between 2 transaction id's

Tags: blockchain, privacy, mixing

Is there a blockchain tool/code that takes two BTC transaction ID's and determines a distance between them.

It's 2017 and Bitcoin Privacy (aka trying to walk around in the public without a sign over you saying how much money you have in your pocket) is still left entirely to the user. I'm trying to explore different methods of adding privacy to bitcoin to protect myself but I have not found a good way to measure how well one method works vs a different method. Something like blockchain.info's taint tool (now hidden on their site) is nice but feels clumsey when trying to determine familiarity between two addresses or transactions. I clearly know that the two addresses are related but want to determine how trivial/untrivial it is to determine that on the blockchain

**Update** Distance is a vague term but maybe intentionally. Distance could, for example, be a combination of: the number of transactions required to get from TX A to TX B assuming there is a path, or a weight that includes the size of transaction.

Comment: This is a tough one. Basically you need to have the blockchain in a graph structure, and then you can calculate the distance between two transaction vertices. Post two tx hashes and i can see if i can try calculating that.